# Get titleblock information from autocad drawing in PDF form

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I have a folder filled with autocad drawings which is savedis all saved in a PDF format. I was wondering if there is any way possible to retrieve the drawing number, sheet number, and description on drawing and place them into a column in excel.

I have looked around youtube and did a few google searches, but I am not sure what to reference as an example.

I would like to go through a folder of autocad drawings in PDF form and categorize them based on drawing number, sheet number, and description on drawing and place them into a column in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether or not those drawings have layers, it will be easier... Have a look at Acrobat Pro API. I know you can read the content of PDF files with that. To have this API, you need to have the Acrobat Pro (paid) version. I am probably sure some other ways exists with either OpenOffice or other open source softwares...